# How to take votes and rank images using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

I'm trying to build a php ranking system where users can rank an image on a scale of 1-5.

Depending on how an image is ranked decides what its place on the leaderboard (rank number) would be. The rank should change depending on the different ratings it receives from users.

An example of this is the ranking system here. http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/601966 (Right hand side, lower down the page.)

I'm just looking for any information which would help me achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing i'm just looking for advice.

Comment: Maybe this can help you as a start point [Building Web Reputation Systems](http://www.amazon.com/Building-Reputation-Systems-Randy-Farmer/dp/059615979X)

Comment: Hi John, don't be disheartened, but the reason you're getting downvotes is because you haven't tried anything. This isn't a place to ask for advice really, its a place to ask for help on specific matters. e.g. "How do I order my mysql query by the 'vote' column".

Answer (score 1):

Create a table called votes and tie it to your images table:

VOTES:

vote_id INT(11) PK

user_id INT(11)

image_id INT(11)

score TINYINT(1)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you're going to need to know:

You need a database. In your database you need to store each of the images you're ranking, do this in a table called "images". In this table you will give each image an "auto-incrementing" primary key. (this means that for each new row you add to the database the primary key will AUTOMATICALLY be +1 from the row before). This means that each image has a UNIQUE row number next to it - identifying that specific row. Call this column `id`. (we will reference it in other tables in the column `image_id`).

Next you need a table called "votes". In this table you can store all sorts of information you might need, but simply all you'll need to store is the unique image number from the "images" table and the value of the vote that someone has cast. You'll end up with something like this:

```
image_id | vote_value
1        | 3
2        | 5
1        | 3
4        | 1
4        | 3
```

Now you can query this information to get your leaderboard. The query might look something like this:

```
SELECT image_id, SUM(vote_value) AS rank FROM votes GROUP BY image_id ORDER_BY rank;
```

That will give you a list of "image_id"s ordered by their rank (i.e. the total of all the votes).

Then you can go back to your images table and get the information for that image out of that table.

```
SELECT name, url FROM images WHERE id=#image_id we got above#;
```

Hope this helps you. :) If you get stuck come back and ask again.

Comment: I want it so that depending on what the user ranks the image (1-5), the image score increases and decreases.

Comment: How do i make it so if a users chooses 3,4 or 5 the image vote value increases by 1, but if they choose 2 or 1 it will decrease by 1.

Comment: Sounds like you need a column in your images table just called "score". This will start at `0` and then every time a user makes a vote you either need to `+1` to that column value or `-1` to that value. e.g. `UPDATE images_table SET score_value = score_value-1`

Comment: Can I increase or decrease the value by 2?